# What is "camera:/" when I connect my Camera to Kubuntu?

Tags: usb, kubuntu, kde, camera, dolphin

Using Kubuntu.

When I connect my Camera to the system through an usb cable, a prompt will be shown at the right bottom corner:

[image]

After clicking "Open with File Manager":

[image]

Dolphin opens with the path to be `camera:/`.

What's the meaning of `camera:/` here and how does Kubuntu handle my camera here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'camera:/' is a KDE kio/kio-slave/protocol. More:

**KIO**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO

> KIO (acronym of KDE Input/Output) is system library incorporated into
>   KDE Frameworks 5 and KDE Software Compilation 4. It provides access to
>   files, web sites and other resources through a single consistent
>   API. Applications, such as Konqueror and Dolphin,...

**Camera**

http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/solid/html/classSolid_1_1Camera.html#_details

> This device interface is available on digital camera devices.
>
> A digital camera is a device used to transform images into data.
>   Nowaday most digital cameras are multifunctional and able to take
>   photographs, video or sound. On the system side they are a particular
>   type of device holding data, the access method can be different from
>   the typical storage device

http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/using-kde.html

> Open konqueror, enter camera:/ into the URL bar. You can then select
>   the camera (USB cameras are autodetected) and descend into the camera
>   filesystem like any other UNIX directory.

Answer (score 0):

The linux kernel provides drivers that you can use in order to read/write/use various devices.

Unlike Windows that creates a drive for hard drivers/cdroms/flash drives etc, linux creates a file with a set of instructions that allow you to access that device. That file is located in /dev/ and the process by witch you access it is called *mounting*

So you plug in the camera, the system detects it and it creates that file in /dev/ that you need to mount in order to access. Ubuntu usually auto-mounts the devices for you, and that is probably what you are experiencing there. The usual mount point for devices is in */media/* or */mnt/* depending on the linux distribution (for ubuntu it's /media/).

You can manually mount and unmount devices using the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and executing the **mount** and **umount** commands which you can use the **--help** attributes on, read their manual pages using **man mount** and **man umount** or google about them.

You should read a little about the linux file system in order to understand how it does all this and how handy it becomes when you need to expand a folder size or create logical volumes.

Comment: But, what's the meaning of 'camera:/' here?

Comment: it's basically a link for you to access what is stored on that device.